# Function wont run inside for each loop inside another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Could someone point out to me why the patientMatch function doesn't appear to run. I need to match the exam info with the patients information to display on a table. Running the function outside of the displayExams functions has no issues, but once its inside the displayExams function it doesnt run. Also logging out patientMatch inside the displayExams function comes back with undefined.

```
function examPatientMatch(exam) {
    for (let i = 0; i < patients.length; i++) {
        if ( exam === patients[i].PATIENT_ID  ) {
            return patiens[i]
        } else {
            console.log('not it')
        }   
    }
}

function displayExams(exams) {
    let examHTML = '';

    exams.forEach((exam, index) => {

        
        let patientId = exam.patient_Id;
        // let imgStudyDays = exam.Diag_to_img_study_days;
        // let imgStudyHrs = exam.Diagnosis_to_imaging_time_hrs;
        // let imgDesc = exam.Image_study_description;
        let studyMod = exam.study_modality;
        let keyFind = exam.key_findings;
        let img = exam.png_filename;
        let examId = exam.exam_Id;

        examPatientMatch(exam)
   
        examHTML += `
        <div class="exam-row" data-index="${index}">
        <div class="cell" data-title="Patient ID"><a>${patientId}</a></div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Exam ID">${examId}</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Xray"><img src="https://ohif-hack-diversity-covid.s3.amazonaws.com/covid-png/${img}" alt="Xray"></div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Key FIndings">${keyFind}</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Study Modality">${studyMod}</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Age">51</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Gender">Male</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="BMI">37.7</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Zip Code">722</div>
        </div>`
    });
    examTable.innerHTML += examHTML;
}
```

Comment: could you share the `exams` data structure ?

Comment: Currently you’re not doing anything with the return value of `examPatientMatch(exam)`, so it won’t do anything but log to the console

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide more details about your code.

if you declare a function inside another function for using the inner function, first YOU MUST call the parent function at least once.

check the names of function for any typo you may accidentally wrote.
because if you do and you are not in `use strict` mode you not gonna get any errors.

javascript has 2 phase when it comes to your code.
creation phase and execution phase. during creation phase variables are created and their values are set to undefined and in the execution phase actual values will be set. so if you do not declare a function you call, you will have reference error. as you don't and you see undefined the declaration was successful. so maybe in `examPatientMatch` function the if statement never match and nothing will return except undefined

i have some tips to tell you when i saw your code.

1 - i see you want to find match exam in the list of patiens array.
it is better to pass object and array to the function. in this way you can reuse the function later.

```
function findItemInListByKey(object, array, key) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if ( exam === array[i][key]  ) {
            return array[i];
        } else {
            console.log('not it')
        }   
    }
}

findItemInListByKey(exam, patiens,'PATIENT_ID')
```

2- in foreach call back you try to access `patient_Id` lowercase but in
`examPatientMatch` function you try to check and object with a value
you should do `exam.patient_Id === patients[i].PATIENT_ID`.

you can use Destructuring assignment for exam object

```
let examHTML = '';

 exams.forEach((exam, index) => {

   const { 
    patient_Id,
    Diag_to_img_study_days,
    Diagnosis_to_imaging_time_hrs,
    Image_study_description,
    study_modality,
    key_findings,
    png_filename,
    exam_Id } = exam;

     examPatientMatch(exam)
   
        examHTML += `
        <div class="exam-row" data-index="${index}">
        <div class="cell" data-title="Patient ID"><a>${patientId}</a></div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Exam ID">${examId}</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Xray"><img src="https://ohif-hack-diversity-covid.s3.amazonaws.com/covid-png/${img}" alt="Xray"></div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Key FIndings">${keyFind}</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Study Modality">${studyMod}</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Age">51</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Gender">Male</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="BMI">37.7</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Zip Code">722</div>
        </div>`
 });

examTable.innerHTML += examHTML;
```

3- you can use javascript high order function called `find` its much cleaner way to deal with finding objects in array.
so insted of writing functions like  `examPatientMatch`
you can do this:

```
const match = patients.find(element => element.PATIENT_ID === exam.patient_Id)
// or exam if you sure exam is not object in your function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I was able to find the problem. Was a minor issue due to **displayExam** function being called before patient data was fetched causing it to show undefined.

As for why I'm using **patient_Id** and **PATIENT_ID it** is due to how the data was created.

I will try the .find method to help clean up my code. Thank you all once again.